# How can I access which fields are placed in a report design with Devexpress Xtrareport in C#?

Tags: c#, devexpress, xtrareport, devexpress-mvc, report-designer

I have about 50 fields that users can add to their reports. I need to know which of these 50 fields users have placed in their designs on the report. Because sometimes these fields can be empty, I need to check this.

How can I access which fields are placed on report designs in c#?

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

[image]

I examined the forms on the devexpress side but I could not get this result.

Answer (score 1):

Each band (Detail in your case) has property [Controls](https://docs.devexpress.com/XtraReports/DevExpress.XtraReports.UI.XRControl.Controls).
Iterate through it and check [DataBinding](https://docs.devexpress.com/XtraReports/DevExpress.XtraReports.UI.XRControl.DataBindings) of each control.

```
foreach (XRControl control in this.Detail.Controls) {
  if (control.DataBindings != null) {
    var binding = control.DataBindigs[0];
    
    // your logic here 
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. 



XtraReport rep = new XtraReport();
rep.LoadLayout(ms);
rep.DataSource = listLabelCharacteristics.ToList();
ReportPrintTool printTool = new ReportPrintTool(rep);
printTool.Print();




This is how I fetch and print the data. When I try to use the code fragment in your answer, I cannot reach the detail band. Could you please explain in more detail?

Comment: You have to use reflection to access Detail in your case, since you creatre an instance of XtraReport (generic class) not one of its descendants.

Comment: The `XtraReport` class has the [Bands](https://docs.devexpress.com/XtraReports/DevExpress.XtraReports.UI.XtraReportBase.Bands) property which gives you access to all bands. Use the following code before displaying the print preview:

DetailBand band = (DetailBand)rep.Bands[BandKind.Detail];